# Generate key for a software developed using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, copy-protection, license-key

Hai guys,
        I ve developed a salary calculating software using vb.net.... Its working fine and i ve converted it to an exe file... My drawback is it can be copied and pasted in another system very easily... I want to generate a key for the exe file and while installing the key should be used and when installation is completed ,the key should not be used again... Is this ya secured one or give me some ideas how it can be done....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many product on the market that will help you generate software keys, for example www.softwareshield.com and www.exeshield.com  Or simply do a [Google Search](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=software+copy+protection).

For more serious protection you can use a hardware key that unlocks your software, for example http://www.matrixlock.de/english/index.htm

Comment: Hardware keys are generally considered a bad idea. They are very inconvenient for the user. A lot of people will not tolerate them unless the software is so great that it's worth the trouble... Hardware keys would definitely be a big reason to look for alternatives if I were looking for software.

Answer (score 2):

It all depends on your adience.

**If you are targetting end-users / home-users**: no matter what you do, your software will be hacked (if it is good enough).

**If you target the enterprise**: Companies are mostly willing to buy your software, and do not copy to other companies. They have far more to loose when running illegal software. But also they are the first to complain if they cannot distribute your software using their distribution  system. And this system will be blocked by your copy protection scheme.

*Conclusion*: Implement the simplest and cheapest protection scheme you can find. And also find a way you can bypass it easily if you want enterprises as your customer.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to sign your assembly, and have some form of online authentication process to manage the keys.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever copy protection scheme you implement....just make sure that your paying users don't get a lot of discomfort from it.... You want to keep bad users from copying your software without permission, but when good users get problems because of faults in your copy protection software, you will lose a lot of credit.